# How to know who is the Manager in a particular OU in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

Juts want to know if anyone has already done this. How to know who is the Manager in a particular OU in Active Directory. I was able to get this in google but its not really what I need.

```
PS P:\> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'OU=Users,OU=Account Reps,OU=AR,DC=com' | Format-list *


City                     :
Country                  :
DistinguishedName        : OU=Users,OU=Account Reps,OU=AR,DC=com
LinkedGroupPolicyObjects : {cn={E8F56E1D-8B38-4698-B79B-76EB0150B8DA},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=nhsrx,DC=com}
ManagedBy                :
Name                     : Users
ObjectClass              : organizationalUnit
ObjectGUID               : 7dcd2bdd-fa1a-497f-8f5c-73260c3a0cb8
PostalCode               :
State                    :
StreetAddress            :
PropertyNames            : {City, Country, DistinguishedName, LinkedGroupPolicyObjects...}
AddedProperties          : {}
RemovedProperties        : {}
ModifiedProperties       : {}
PropertyCount            : 11
```

Answer (score 1):

With "Get-*" functions in the ActiveDirectory module, you generally have to ask for the specific attributes you care about because returning everything by default would put undue stress on your domain controllers. You do that with the `-Properties` parameter like this.

```bsh
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'OU=Users,OU=Account Reps,OU=AR,DC=com' -Properties managedBy
```

For the `managedBy` property specifically, all you're going to get back is another DN value. So if you want the details for that object, you need to run a separate query for it.

```bsh
$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'OU=Users,OU=Account Reps,OU=AR,DC=com' -Properties managedBy
$manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $ou.managedBy
```

Keep in mind that OU managers can be set to object types other than users (like groups). So if you can't guarantee that, you might be better using `Get-ADObject`.

Comment: issue was that Managedby Properties is always blank for the OU's.

Comment: Right, because you didn't ask for that attribute to be returned in your query.